# Starts with and include regex in Mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb

In my `attributes` key I want to find in the array records that are `Special` and has `latenight : True`.

```
"attributes" : [ "Alcohol: none", "BikeParking: True", "Special: {'dessert': False, 'latenight': False, 'lunch': False, 'dinner': False, 'breakfast': False, 'brunch': False}" ]
```

So far this is what I have `db.restaurant.find({ attributes: {$in :[/^Special/]} });`. But I do not know where to go from there. I want the regex to contain `latenight : True` as well.

Comment: I guess you need `/^Special.*latenight : True/` to get entries starting with `Special` and then also having `latenight : True` in the string.

Comment: I removed the sql like comparison because I do not want people to flag for duplicate. This is not a duplicate question. I have searched the website extensively before I ask.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I will try that and get back with you.

Comment: Now that you've updated your question the duplicate seems less likely to be correct... Have you stored an object as a string?

Comment: @ctwheels I think it comes as a string, I got it from the yelp database. Everything in the attributes column is a string. I think it would have been easier without that. That is why I was think of it as a `sql LIKE` statement with that starts with something, and contains something.

Comment: @Jam1 it would definitely be easier if it was converted to an object. I would look into a solution that converts the string into an object and then add that to attributes instead as such `"attributes" : [ "Alcohol: none", "BikeParking: True", {Special: {'dessert': False, 'latenight': False, 'lunch': False, 'dinner': False, 'breakfast': False, 'brunch': False}} ]`, that way you can properly query it.
`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this did the trick `/^Special.*'latenight': True/` I had what you originally had early, seems like we were on the same page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regex that you are looking for is

```
/^Special.*'latenight': True/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AFaRrW/1/).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `Special` - a literal string
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `'latenight': True` - a literal substring.

Note that you may replace the literal space with `\s+` to match any 1+ whitespace chars.

Comment: Hey thanks man, I had figured this out, but thanks for the extra information and clarity. I think others will find this helpful as json format can be complicated at times.